# Variable outside scope

Tags: php, variables, scope

The `$base` variable in the code below is apparently outside the scope, however the `$urlS` and `$urlE` variables are not? Can someone explain why this is?

```
class Yahoo {
    //Code below to retrieve live currency rates from yahoo
private static $base = 'USD';
private static $urlS = LIVE_FEED_YAHOO;
private static $urlE = '=X&f=l1';
private $rate;

public function __construct($toCurr) {
$url = self::$urlS.$base.$toCurr.self::$urlE;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `self::` before `$base`, as you did with `$urlS` and `$urlE`:

```
$url = self::$urlS . self::$base . $toCurr . self::$urlE;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it's always the small things I miss!